# Reading from file and passing it to another command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a two column tab delimited file the contains input for a command.

The input file looks like this:

```
 2795.bam   2865.bam
 2825.bam   2865.bam
 2794.bam   2864.bam
```

the command line is:

```
macs2 callpeak -t trt.bam -c ctrl.bam -n Macs.name.bam --gsize hs --nomodel
```

where trt.bam are the names of files in column 1 and ctrl.bam are the names of files in col2.

what I trying is to read these values from input file and run them.

To do achieve this I am doing following:

```
cat temp | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 }' | macs2 callpeak -t $1 -c $2 -n Macs.$1 --gsize hs --nomodel
```

This is failing. The error that I get is:

```
usage: macs2 callpeak [-h] -t TFILE [TFILE ...] [-c [CFILE [CFILE ...]]]
                      [-f {AUTO,BAM,SAM,BED,ELAND,ELANDMULTI,ELANDEXPORT,BOWTIE,BAMPE,BEDPE}]
                      [-g GSIZE] [--keep-dup KEEPDUPLICATES]
                      [--buffer-size BUFFER_SIZE] [--outdir OUTDIR] [-n NAME]
                      [-B] [--verbose VERBOSE] [--trackline] [--SPMR]
                      [-s TSIZE] [--bw BW] [-m MFOLD MFOLD] [--fix-bimodal]
                      [--nomodel] [--shift SHIFT] [--extsize EXTSIZE]
                      [-q QVALUE | -p PVALUE] [--to-large] [--ratio RATIO]
                      [--down-sample] [--seed SEED] [--tempdir TEMPDIR]
                      [--nolambda] [--slocal SMALLLOCAL] [--llocal LARGELOCAL]
                      [--broad] [--broad-cutoff BROADCUTOFF]
                      [--cutoff-analysis] [--call-summits]
                      [--fe-cutoff FECUTOFF]
macs2 callpeak: error: argument -t/--treatment: expected at least one argument
```

In an ideal situation this should be taking inputs like this:

```
macs2 callpeak -t 2795.bam -c 2865.bam -n Macs.2795 --gsize hs --nomodel
```

Where Macs is a standalone software that runs on linux. In the present situation, the software is failing to read the input from the file.

Any inputs are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Check your question for typos: `trt.bam` vs. `try.bam`.

Comment: Please post expected output in your post too and let us know.

Comment: edits Done. Please check now.

Comment: Given tab-separated input in `temp`, what do you think `cat temp | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 }'` will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want to achieve is a loop over all lines in your input file. In bash, you can achieve this as :

```
while read -r tfile cfile; do
   macs2 callpeak -t "$tfile" -c "$cfile" -n "Macs.$tfile" --gsize hs --nomodel
done < "input_file.txt"
```

See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (cfr. Sundeep's comment)

**original answer:**

```
while read -a a; do
   macs2 callpeak -t "${a[0]}" -c "${a[1]}" -n "Macs.${a[0]}" --gsize hs --nomodel
done < "input_file.txt"
```

This will read the input file `input_file.txt` line by line and store it in a bash array named `a` using `read -a a`. From that point forward, you process your command with the variables `${a[0]}` and `${a[1]}`.

Comment: @Angelo Why do you need a for loop? This will process your complete file.

Comment: You have done this using while loop. That works perfectly, I was curious to know how to structure this with for loop.

Comment: Nice answer but output is not exactly like expected. Macs.2795.bam should not contain .bam. Possible correction: `Macs.$(echo ${a[0]//.*})`

Comment: @Angelo the answer is that one shouldn't use for-loop to read a file in bash - https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @ReneKnop I believe this was a typo by the OP. In his question, he also writes in the original command line: `macs ... -n Macs.name.bam ...` To this end I did not remove the `.bam`. If you want to remove the `.bam` in the `-n` argument you can use `macs ... -n Macs.${a[0]%.bam} ...`

Comment: @kvantour Oh right, i did not say anything :-) Btw: `Macs.${a[0]%.bam}` is nice short solution. Thanks for that.